# Difference between Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) and Environment.SystemDirectory for System32 folder

Tags: c#, .net, windows, special-folders, system32

I want to get the path `system32` path on 32 bit Windows and `SysWOW64` on 64 bit Windows. Both `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)` and `Environment.SystemDirectory` work fine. Which one should I prefer and use? I am using .NET 2.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could prefer using

```
Environment.SystemDirectory
```

this is because, the .NET framework already knows what folder you need and under the covers makes a direct call to

```
Win32Native.GetSystemDirectory
```

from the underlying `kernerl32.dll`.. (and then does a quick permission check)

if you use,

```
Environment.GetFolderPath
```

then you have to pass in an enum, and under the covers the `GetFolderPath` has to do a quick enum validity check. Once done, it calls the native

```
Win32Native.SHGetFolderPath
```

passing in the integer equivalent of the type of folder needed.

this calls the underlying method from the native `shfolder.dll`
and this method again would have a switch/case like check based on the folder requested and finally invoke the system directory logic.

based on the above 2 flows, the

```
Environment.SystemDirectory
```

should be more suited and probably quicker for you. (i haven't really measured)

Comment: Funny enough, kernel32.dll has the same name even on 64 bit windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364741/does-64-bit-windows-use-kernel64