# System32 Folder on a 64-bit system

Tags: 64-bit, cmd

I have a cmd file that runs on 32 bit Vista system.

I notice that the code has references to the system32 driver folder.

I'm wondering whether the code could potentially run on a 64 bit Windows 7 system. So I guess my question is
Does a 64 bit system contain a system32 folder?

Be very grateful for any replies.

Comment: Doesn't this belong on superuser?

Comment: Similar on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/157294/why-doesnt-windows-7-ultimate-64-bit-contain-folder-system64-like-system32-in

Answer (score 14):

The System32 folder in 64-bit Windows actually contains the 64-bit files, and 32-bit programs running under WOW64 would generally go looking in System32 for the 32-bit DLLs etc. that they can call - but they'll find the 64-bit ones instead. Therefore the OS redirects all 32-bit applications' requests for the System32 folder to the SysWOW64 folder, which contains 32-bit system files.

Comment: So the `system 32` folder has all the `64-bit DLLS`, and the `SysWOW64 ` folder contains all the `32-bit DLLS`? WTF? Why isn't it `System32` for `32-bit DLLS` and `System64` for `64-bit DLLS`?

Comment: @B1KMusic "the intent was to rename System32, but so many applications hard-coded for that path, that it wasn't feasible to remove it" http://stackoverflow.com/a/950011/995714

Comment: @B1KMusic don't somebody know, why my system32 on 64 bit windows contains 32bit versions of cmd, sfc, dism and so on, even after i reinstalled windows from mediacreationtool?

Answer (score 7):

Windows has a technology called WoW 64 (Windows-on-Windows 64-bit) that allows 32-bit applications (even compiled ones written in C/C++, etc.) to run on 64-bit Windows.

In addition to the System32 folder, a 64-bit Windows installation has a SysWow64 folder that has 32-bit versions of the files that you'll find in System32.

To be clear, references to System32 get redirected when running from a 32-bit process (unless the process disables this redirection, which is possible). As a result, if you have a .CMD file that references System32, it's actually going to read from the SysWow64 directory.

Comment: Many thanks, I think I'm getting the picture. 

How do you know if your application is 32 bit?

Comment: Is this a command-shell script (.CMD file)? That's the impression I got from your post. If so it will execute anywhere, and I'm not certain what you meant by "references to System32", but I figured it was directly accessing files there.

If this is a compiled application, and you have Visual C++ installed, you can use LINK /DUMP /HEADERS <file>.exe, and at the very top under FILE HEADER VALUES you'll see 'machine' with a name in parentheses. If it's (i386), then it's 32-bit. I forget what x64 lists, but it might be (x64) or (amd64).

Answer (score 2):

**System32** is the name of the folder that contains important operating system files.

Early versions of 64-bit Windows XP only ran 64-bit applications. This made sense:

- you run 16-bit applications on 16-bit Windows
- you run 32-bit applications on 32-bit Windows
- you run 64-bit applications on 64-bit Windows

And early versions of 64-bit Windows XP were 64-bit, and only supported running 64-bit applications.

And since all the folders names stay the same, you can simply recompile your application as 64-bit (and not have to change **anything** else - including your accidentally hard-coded paths), and it will just work.

### Emulate 32-bit OS on 64-bit Windows

Very quickly it became obvious that only being able to run 64-bit applications on 64-bit Windows, would prevent some people from upgrading to 64-bit Windows. So [an emulation layer was created to allow you to run 32-bit applications on a 64-bit operating system.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081222-00/?p=19763)

It was called WOW64:  `Windows` `on` `Windows64`:

- This emulation layer simulates the x86 architecture, virtualizing the CPU, the file system, the registry, the environment variables, the system information functions, all that stuff.
- If a 32-bit program tries to look at the system, it will see a 32-bit system.
- For example, if the program calls the GetSystemInfo function to see what processor is running, it will be told that it's running on a 32-bit processor, with a 32-bit address space, in a world with a 32-bit sky and 32-bit birds in the 32-bit trees.
- And that's the point of the emulation: To keep the 32-bit program happy by simulating a 32-bit execution environment.

The problem is where should these 32-bit applications store all their 32-bit files, and configure the locations of their 32-bit DLLs, and load 32-bit operating system support files?

We already know where *native* applications store their stuff.

```
| Native Application  |
|---------------------|
| C:\Windows\System32 |
| C:\Program Files    |
| HKCU\Software       |
```

This is all correct and right; if you simply recompile your 32-bit application as 64-bit: everything works. All these locations are still correct.

### 32-bit in a 64-bit world

But now since we're going to bend-over backwards in order to accomdoate non-64 bit applications, we have to find someplace for them to have their old 32-bit OS files, and store their 32-bit data, and have their 32-bit programs, with 32-bit shared components:

```
| Native Application  | Emulated 32-bit           |
|---------------------|---------------------------|
| C:\Windows\System32 | C:\Windows\SysWOW64       |
| C:\Program Files    | C:\Program Files (x86)    |
| HKCU\Software       | HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node |
```

A problem is that:

- if a 64-bit program asks for `C:\Windows\System32`, it damn well better **get** 64-bit files
- if a 32-bit program asks for `C:\Windows\System32`, it damn well better **get** 32-bit files

This means that if a 32-bit process **ask** for some of these file locations, Windows has to transparently redirect the call to the 32-bit folders and registry keys.

If a 32-bit program, that **thinks** it's running on an old 32-bit operating system, asks for a 32-bit location, it needs to be given the "real" location:

```
| Native Application  | Emulated 32-bit asks for  | Is actually given         |
|---------------------|---------------------------|---------------------------|
| C:\Windows\System32 | C:\Windows\System32       | C:\Windows\SysWOW64       |
| C:\Program Files    | C:\Program Files          | C:\Program Files (x86)    |
| HKCU\Software       | HKCU\Software             | HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node |
```

If you don't want your 32-bit application to be subject to all this emulation and thunking, then the solution is obvious:

- create a 64-bit application for a 64-bit operating system

Stop creating a 32-bit application, and then complaining when the emulation layer causes you to go through emulation. Your application is the misbehaving oddball; fix it.

Comment: an answer to a more than 8 years old question! I came to close-flag it and am leaving with an upvote instead. That's rare... Nice and understandable explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 64 bit has a System32 folder.

Whether your file will still run, however, is a more complex problem. It *might*, and depends entirely on what it relies on; if it's relying on drivers in the wrong way, it will fail as 32 bit drivers just don't work on 64 bit systems.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to reply .. but when you say relying on drivers in the wrong way, what do you mean?

Comment: Without knowing more about the situation, I really can't say! If your code is relying on some technicality of a specific driver, that driver might be different under Win64, and so fails. Can you post the code in question?