# Color for the PROMPT (just the PROMPT proper) in cmd.exe and PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, command-prompt, prompt, cmd

So in Bash you just configure `PS1` to add colors to your prompt. I'm talking about the prompt proper, not the color of the foreground (text) or the background. And it's really easy in Bash and it helps a lot if you need to find your commands in a sea of messy text output.

Can you achieve the same for `cmd.exe`, or as a fallback, for PowerShell? A colored prompt?

I don't know if it could be done in the old days before Win32 by loading `ANSI.SYS`. I think that was just to make the foreground and the background colorful. But I might be wrong. And anyway, those days are gone, and in our modern times (I know), we're using `cmd.exe`, or PowerShell.

I know both cmd.exe and PowerShell are capable of colored output. For cmd.exe, just run `color /?` to find out. But my question is not about the foreground and the background, that's all known to humankind - it's about just changing the prompt color for cmd.exe, probably via the `PROMPT` environment variable as via the `PS1` variable for Bash? Is it possible?

And no, Cygwin is not an alternative for this. I'm a Cygwin user with MinTTY and all, and I love it. But I still want my `cmd.exe` prompt colored, too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Building on @KriZ's answer, the ANSI escape sequences work perfectly in Windows 10 `cmd.exe` as of 2019. Didn't need to explicitly call out `ansi.sys` or copy any files. It just worked out of the box in Windows 10.

For example,

```
set PROMPT=$E[1;37m[user@machine:$E[1;35m$P ]$$ $E[1;37m
```

Produces:

[image: example colored prompt]

(Notice the space after the final `$`)

Everything before the drive is colored in bold white and the drive/folder is bold pink, and everything after the final `$` is bold white.

The format for the colors is:

```
$E[bold_or_not;colorm
```

With m always following the color number. bold_or_not = 0 or 1. Here's a guide for the colors:

> ```
> 0     Turn Off Attributes
> 1     High Intensity
> 2     Normal Intensity
> 4     Underline (mono only)
> 5     Blink
> 7     Reverse Video
> 8     Invisible
> 30    Black
> 31    Red
> 32    Green
> 33    Yellow
> 34    Blue
> 35    Magenta
> 36    Cyan
> 37    White
> 40    Black
> 41    Red
> 42    Green
> 43    Yellow
> 44    Blue
> 45    Magenta
> 46    Cyan
> 47    White
> ```

Colors Source: https://kb.iu.edu/d/aamm

Comment: One note is that the $E[x;y;zm seems to support more than two items. There may be a little more nuance to being able to select colors than I figured out for my post above.

Comment: `PROMPT $E[1;36m[%username%@%computername%]:$E[1;35m$P$G$S$E[1;37m`

Comment: For  German date and time as `31.10 12:30`, removing excessive precision with `$h`, plus folder: `$E[1;37m::$s$E[1;35m$d$h$h$h$h$h$E[0;36m$s$t$h$h$h$h$h$h$E[1;37m$s$p$E[0;37m$s`

Answer (score 17):

You can add a Prompt function to your profile in Powershell to pretty much do whatever you want with the prompt. So for instance something like this:

```
function prompt
{
    Write-Host "PS $(get-location)>"  -nonewline -foregroundcolor Magenta
    return ' '
}
```

To open or create your PowerShell profile, run this:

```
if(Test-Path $profile){notepad $profile}else{New-Item -path $profile -type file -force}
```

Comment: And you should return at least space. Otherwise PowerShell will append 'PS>' at the end.

Comment: Thanks - works nicely, after doing `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` (for simplicity's sake). But without having done much searching for how it was possible on PowerShell I was sure that it was possible. The ANSI hack for `cmd.exe`, on the other hand, that's sensational! :-)

Answer (score 14):

follow this link. There's an ANSI hack developped for the CMD.exe shell

[link to ansi hack](http://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=188&lang=en)

I've tried it on my win 7 professional SP1 and works like a charm

[image]

Comment: Phantastic, thanks! I got it working, too. The instructions in the `readme.txt` are good, just one thing missing: On 64 bit systems, you have to copy the two DLLs - `AnsiSupport.dll` and `DllSpoof.dll` - to the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` folder instead of the `C:\Windows\system32` folder. ([Be sure to read up on the folder trickery unless you know!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949959)) This was the case on my system - Win7 Pro 64 bit. Working fine and colorful now - thanks again, that's **great**!

Comment: **CAVEAT**: This is **not** a 1:1 replacement plus ANSI colors. Although there's no problem most of the time, some things may well stop working. One example I've come across is the `powercfg.exe` utility. The 32 bit ANSI hack will pick up stuff in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` (32 bit), the original one stuff in `C:\Windows\System32` (64 bit). With `powercfg`, this does make a big difference. The 32 bit version wouldn't tell me why my computer woke up. Definitely keep this in mind lest you get bitten.

Comment: what are these non-standard two additional buttons on the top right corner of the `cmd.exe` window ?

Comment: These are additional buttons from Ultramon. Bought that licensed version a couple years ago and can't live without it anymore. The buttons allow any window (including cmd) to either be stretched or moved to the other screen by clicking on them. That combined with 'the each screen has its own taskbar' makes it a must have for dual or triple screen people.

Comment: On Win 10 ansi colors work out of the box without any hacks

Answer (score 6):

This is all good information but an important thing that I didn't see addressed is how to make the custom prompt appear each time you run a command prompt.  In older Windows, such as XP and before, you would put the PROMPT environment variable in the `AUTOEXEC.BAT` file but in Windows 7 through Windows 10, you would make it permanent as follows:

- Open the `Run` prompt by using the Windows `key + R`
- Type "systempropertiesadvanced" (without the quotes) and hit `ENTER`
- This will open the System Properties dialog box (You can also right click My Computer and choose Properties to get this)
- Select the "Advanced" Tab at the top
- Choose "Environment Variables" near the bottom
- In the lower area, in the "System variables" area, look and see if you currently have a variable called "Prompt" (capitalization doesn't matter)
- If so, edit the prompt variable and your changes with be permanent
- If not, click "New" near the bottom and for Variable name, enter PROMPT and for the variable value, whatever you want it to be.  The default prompt has a variable value of $P$G
- Click OK
- Run the command prompt to test
- DONE
- Note:  I use a custom command prompt which looks like the Texas flag.  The Variable value for this is:
  `$e[1;44m*$e[41m▀▀$e[0;1m $P$G`

(The white bar is made by holding down ALT and typing 223 on the keypad on the right.  There are two of these characters in this prompt.)

Comment: Okay that's brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple colors (very useful for identifying components of your prompt, typical in Unix):

```
function prompt {
    Write-Host ("@") -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Magenta
    Write-Host ("$env:COMPUTERNAME") -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host (":") -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Magenta
    Write-Host ($(Get-Location)) -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host (">") -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Red
    return " "
}
```

[image]

(`COMPUTERNAME` was explicitly written here, but it actually gets replaced by the value of the environment variable).

And you can add random colors (taken from [here](http://mshforfun.blogspot.com.ar/2006/05/perfect-prompt-for-windows-powershell.html); [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847739.aspx) has a similar version; both have other very interesting tweaks):

```
function prompt
{
    $random = new-object random
    $color=[System.ConsoleColor]$random.next(1,16)
    Write-Host ("PS " + $(get-location) +">") -nonewline -foregroundcolor $color
    return " "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all existing answers, this is my command prompt (if you like it, you can use it)

```
$E[7;33m$P$_$E[0;37m[$E[0;32m%username%@%computername%$E[0;36m$S$D$S$T$H$H$H$E[0;37m]$$$E[0;37m$S
```

Just need to add a User Variable `PROMPT` with the above value

Output:

[image]