# How to customize Windows CMD prompt with colors?

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

By prompt, I mean the line where I input command (e.g. in bash, it would be what's in PS1 environment variable). Having it the same color as the application output makes it poorly readable in some cases. Is there a way to add more life to it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to echo with different colors in the Windows command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line)

Comment: @Pekka웃 the linked question is about echo, and my is about prompt. Prompt is *very* special part of console output, so standard tricks like piping through that cmdcolor utility won't work.

Comment: I don't think this is quite what you want but I may be wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297072/color-for-the-prompt-just-the-prompt-proper-in-cmd-exe-and-powershell

Comment: @Pekka웃 well, it involves hijacking cmd process and hooking to WinAPI calls. While I have great respect for Gynvael, I'd like to avoid that - especially since I'm not using cmd.exe but actually ConEmu, which is cmd + bunch of other stuff. If there is no way to do colors with pure cmd, I'll accept such answer too.