# Why are some character constants 1 byte wide, and others 2 bytes wide?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I thought I was beginning to understand Unicode, but this beats me:

```
const
c1 = #1;   --> SizeOf() = 2
c2 = #33;  --> SizeOf() = 2
c3 = #127; --> SizeOf() = 2
c4 = #128; --> SizeOf() = 1
c5 = #160; --> SizeOf() = 1 
c6 = #161; --> SizeOf() = 1 
c7 = #255; --> SizeOf() = 1
```

Can anyone explain?
Delphi XE2, Default Windows-1252 codepage

Thanks
Jan

Comment: note also http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=100685 gotcha

Comment: @Arioch'The - I wonder how is it possible to fix this 'bug' because that really is how Unicode is implemented in Delphi; Ord(Ch) generally depends on default ANSI codepage; you can get different binaries when compile on systems with different ANSI codepages.

Comment: @Serg   

default which ? in same project we can have sources encoded in at least  three different codepages...
----
Personally i think Ord(WideChat) should map to UTF-16 Word if possible.
Ord(AnsiChar) should map to GetACP() Byte, if possible.
Respectively there to be Chr(Byte):AnsiChar and Chr(Word):WideChar;

What to do with MBCS and Unicode Surrogates i don't know, but hope it is rare beast.

Comment: No problems with 'pure' Unicode and {$HIGHCHARUNICODE ON} setting; the problem is when you use Ansi Chars, both with {$HIGHCHARUNICODE} ON and OFF, because as Marian said `Ansi` in Delphi means locale specific and pretty awkward and useless when you need to support multiple Ansi codepages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is documented - see [$HIGHCHARUNICODE](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/HIGHCHARUNICODE_directive_%28Delphi%29) directive

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think it's for the benefit of pre-Unicode code, to make #160 the same character it was in D2007 and earlier.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan After re-reading, I think you're right, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - the feature is bizarre but consistent. Probably there were compatibility reasons for it, same that caused `AnsiUpperCase` to became a unicode function in Delphi 2009.

Comment: Ansi* functions have been misnomed from their inception on. They should have been named LocaleSpecific* instead of Ansi* The character set is just a part of locale specificity.

Comment: @Serg Marco Cantu's book confirms what you say about the reasoning behind this.

Comment: EMBT should have made $HIGHCHARUNICODE=ON the default. I knew of its existence but did not look, assuming consistent behaviour as the standard, and compiler directives for exceptions (e.g for backward compatibility)

Comment: @Jan Even if not for 2009, it should be the default by now!

Comment: @MarjanVenema similar for the System32 directory that contains the x64 DLLs and SysWoW64 the x86 ones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949959/why-do-64bit-dlls-go-to-system32-and-32bit-dlls-to-syswow64-on-64bit-windows