# Why do string constants use wide characters even when formed entirely from 8 bit characters?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I just posted a question about [Unicode character constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297755/unicode-character-constants-delphi), where $HIGHCHARUNICODE appeared to be the reason.
Now with the default $HIGHCHARUNICODE OFF (Delphi XE2), why is this:

```
const
  AllLowByteValues =#$00#$01#$02#$03#$04#$05#$06#$07#$08#$09#$0a#$0b#$0c#$0d#$0e#$0f;
  AllHighByteValues=#$D0#$D1#$D2#$D3#$D4#$D5#$D6#$D7#$D8#$D9#$Da#$Db#$Dc#$Dd#$De#$Df;

==> Sizeof(AllLowByteValues[1])  = 2
==> Sizeof(AllHighByteValues[1]) = 2
```

If "All hexadecimal #$xx 2-digit literals are parsed as AnsiChar" for #$80 ... #$FF, then why is AllHighByteValues a unicode String and not an ANSIString?

Comment: I think these literals are parsed as Ansi and converted to Unicode (because default string type is Unicode)

Comment: Your experiment doesn't actually show how the values are stored. The SizeOf expression is resolved at compile time and doesn't actually inspect the stored value. You need to show that the strings you've defined are actually stored as WideChar values *in the EXE file*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because string constants are `PChar` and so made up of UTF-16 elements.

From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/String_Types):

> String constants are assignment-compatible with the PChar and PWideChar types, which represent pointers to null-terminated arrays of Char and WideChar values.

Comment: Thanks. all thos nitty gritty details ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are not taking that into account that String and Character literals are context-sensitive in D2009+.  If a literal is used in an Ansi context, it will be stored as Ansi.  If a literal is used in a Unicode context, it will be stored as Unicode.  `HIGHCHARUNICODE` only applies to 3-digit numeric Character literals between #128-#255 and 2-digit hex Character literals between #$80-#$FF.  Those particular values are ambiquious between Ansi and Unicode, so `HIGHCHARUNICODE` is used to address the ambiquity.  `HIGHCHARUNICODE` does not apply to other types of literals, including String literals.  If you pass a String or Character literal to `SizeOf()`, there is no Ansi/Unicode context in the source code for the compiler to use, so it is going to use a Unicode context except in the specific case where `HIGHCHARUNICODE` applies, in which case an Ansi context is used if `HICHCHARUNICODE` is OFF.  That is what you are seeing happen.