# How to get the Address of a ntdll function when it's loaded twice?

Tags: ntdll

I intend to hook into a `ntdll` function `ZwTerminateProcess`, but am having a problem with `x64`, because if a `x86` app is running in a windows `x64` , it is loaded with `two ntdlls`:
One from `System32` path and the other one from `SysWOW64`.

Until here I have no problems, except: the first `ntdll(system32)` don't show up when I list `dlls` using  `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` or `EnumProcessModules()` and when I use `GetModuleHandle()` the return is the `hModule` from the second `ntdll(SysWOW64)`.

I was thinking that maybe the first `dll` was loaded with `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE flag` but if it were the case the app would not be able to use the function from the `first ntdll(System32)`. I have tried to hook the `ZwTerminateProcess()` in the second `ntdll` but it doesn't work. Does anyone have some idea of how to help me?

Please let me know if more clarification is required.

Thank you, Douglas.

Comment: The DLL from SysWOW64 is - despite its name - the right one for your 32bit application. The DLL from System32 is the 64bit version. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949959/why-do-64-bit-dlls-go-to-system32-and-32-bit-dlls-to-syswow64-on-64-bit-windows - For finding out why the hook does not work, you should improve your question and maybe show some code.

Comment: yeah, but i need to do a hook in the dll from System32 the problem is i can't get it hModule, the problem isn't the code because what i'm doing is just put a retn, but i'm putting it on the wrong place, with C.E(Cheat Engine 6.2) for example i can put on the right place but with my app i can't..

Comment: GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA('ntdll.dll'),'ZwTerminateProcess');
it returns a wrong address, i already tried with LoadLibraryA() instead of GetModuleHandleA but it keep returns a wrong address

Comment: sorry, i wasn't clear.. i already tried it and the returns was the hModule from the SysWOW64 dll, even i using LoadLibraryA('C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll')

Comment: Try loading from c:\windows\sysnative\ntdll.dll