# OpenGL issue with x64 configuration under visual studio 2010 & windows 7 64bit version

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, glut, glew

I have an opengl program which runs correctly under win32 configuration, but pops up an error when configuring it with x64 in visual studio 2010.

Here are the pictures:

(1) In win32 mode:(correct)
[image]

[image]

2) In X64 mode (colors are wrong, the box frame should always be red, and the cube should  always be green, but...[image][image]

When I move the mouse, the color changed into the following:
[image][image]

and my program has stopped working with "Windows is checking for a solution to the problem..."

But I can get a good result in win32 mode without any issues. I didn't change any codes. So it should be the configuration problem.

Some tips:
(1) I put glut.dll & glut32.dll & glu32.dll & opengl32.dll & freeglut.dll to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 since my os is 64 bit.

(2) For win32 libs such as glut.lib,glut32.lib,glew32.lib,glew32s.lib,freeglut.lib and GLAUX.lib, I put into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib.
    For x64 libs like glut.lib, glut64.lib, glew64.lib, freeglut.lib, I put them into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\amd64.(I didn't include GLAUX.lib in this directory)

Any advice?

***New Tip: I got error only in x64 release mode, the x64 debug version works fine.***

Comment: Show the code where the crash happens. Show the stacktrace and the exact error message (look in the Windows Eventlog for additional details).

Comment: "But I can get a good result in win32 mode without any issues. I didn't change any codes. So it should be the configuration problem." That conclusion does not follow. It can be a 64bit issue in your code (which I consider the most likely case). Beeing sloppy with data types usually results in such behavior when switching to a different ABI.

Comment: @derhass Thanks. I will debug it and focus on the ABI issue.

Comment: @jessehouwing Thank you. But The problem is I didn't get any errors in debug model in x64 configurations. I got error only in x64 release mode. It's a little bit weird.

Comment: In release mode, you can still attach a debugger. In Release mode you can still get a stacktrace. It won't be as detailed, but the compilation mode doesn't change the facts that much (except the colour of your rederings, obviously...)

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer (sorry), but a set of comments that doesn't fit to comment char limit.

So, advices:

- How you suppose to debug it in release mode? Use *debugger* to spot where error happens. We are programmers and can't debug by pictures. We aren't going either to guess where you have a bug.
- find *what exactly changes* when you switching to 64-bit mode:

  - conditional compilation? (`#ifdef`)
  - integer sizes? (GL expects 4 byte int, but you pass 4 byte in 32-bit and 8 byte in 64 bit?)
  - pointer size? you have heap memory issues that present, but just not showing in 32 bit mode. They showing when pointer size changes
  - data alignment?
  - ... etc etc. Too many options
- never play with `\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC\lib\` folder. Instead of moving files around, set path to your libs in Project options / Makefiles.
- Despite of `64` number, `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` [stores 32-bit DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949959/why-do-64-bit-dlls-go-to-system32-and-32-bit-dlls-to-syswow64-on-64-bit-windows). Go to `C:\Windows\System32` for 64-bit ones. Yeah it's confusing. ;) By the way, don't play with this folders too. Instead, put your DLLs to a directory where your executable is.

Comment: Thanks, your advices helped me a lot. I'm not a graphics programmer, just want to use opengl for visualizing my simulation data, so was really confused by this error. When I put more objects in this scene, after running for several seconds, it will crash, as you analyzed, probably it's due to the 4 byte/8 byte size issue or pointer size. Well, I will check it out. And thanks for suggesting not playing with default directories. I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same symptoms as you regarding x64 Release mode.

I was using Qt but calling "raw" opengl calls. I had my triangle disappear in release mode (shader wasn't loading properly) and it ended up being that i wrongly used va_args in a function call. It happened to work in all the Build configs apart from x64.

Go figure!