# Accessing anything GLEW related immediately crashes program in MinGW

Tags: opengl, mingw, glew, clion

Here is the code:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "GL/glew.h"

int main () {
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

When the 'glewExperimental' line is commented out, program exits with 0.

Here is the CMake file (I am using CLion):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(untitled)

add_definitions(-DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES)
add_definitions(-DWINVER=0x0602)
add_definitions(-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0602)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(untitled ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(untitled  glfw3  glew32 opengl32 gdi32)
```

I am using MinGW toolchain on Windows 8.1.

I compiled the GLEW library with the following bat file:

```
gcc -DGLEW_NO_GLU -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -DGLEW_BUILD -o src/glew.o -c src/glew.c

gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32.dll.a -o lib/glew32.dll src/glew.o -L/mingw/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32

ar cr lib/libglew32.a src/glew.o
```

I placed the resulting libglew32.a, libglew32.dll.a in MinGW/lib folder.

I placed teh glew32.dll in Windows/System32 folder.

I placed the GL/glew.h, glxew.h, wglew.h in the MinGW/include folder.

What am I missing?

I cannot figure out why simply assigning a value to that variable throws an exception...

Comment: You should never place dlls in the System32 folder yourself. This folder is ment for system dlls. Simple place them in the folder your executable lies in.

Comment: Your code already defines `GLEW_STATIC`. That means all of this discussion about a DLL version of GLEW is completely irrelevant. You should have built and linked to the static (non-DLL) GLEW library. It is quite possible that after you get that sorted out, your problem might go away - you certainly won't have to worry about where the GLEW DLL goes, since it's not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

As I understood there are two questions to answer:

> Why does my program crash when I include glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; but not when leaving it away?

Your program crashes because it cannot load the glew library. When you leave this line away, no call to glew is made and the program will most likely not even load it.

> Why does my program not find glew32.dll although I copied it into the system32 folder?

If you have a 64-bit operating system, than system32 is the folder where the **64-bit** dlls are placed. I know this sounds sic!, but that's how windows works. 32-bit libraries are located in SysWOW64. This SO-answer contains more details about this: [why-do-64-bit-dlls-go-to-system32-and-32-bit-dlls-to-syswow64-on-64-bit-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949959/why-do-64-bit-dlls-go-to-system32-and-32-bit-dlls-to-syswow64-on-64-bit-windows).

In general you should never place dlls somewhere in the windows folder. This folders are reserved for system libraries/system-wide libraries like drivers etc. The reason for this is, that you get into deep troubles if someone else copies another version of e.g. glew32.dll into the system folder, which will most probably crash you app. The best way to place your own libraries is in the directory your executable lies in.

Comment: Thanks this enlighten my day ! i was starting to become crazy with glut32 giving me errors

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve by adding the following line to CMakeLists.txt

```
add_definitions(-DGLEW_STATIC)
```

I do not understand why the above would work since, to my understanding the following would have had the same affect:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
```