# Suprema BioMini with Java - where should UFLicense.dat be put?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working on a fingerprint recognition Java application for a university project. 
We bought Suprema Biomini Scanner and SDK and I have installed the SDK on my Windows 8 machine. 
I am using Netbeans IDE and I am trying to run the demoUFEJavaJNA.java file. 
The GUI for the sample program launches and when I press init, I get the following output with error 101 which means the System has no license. 
My UFScanner.dll and UFMatcher.dll are located in my Netbeans project workspace and I have put a copy of UFLicense.dat there as well. 
Still the error persists. Any idea how to fix this? 
[image: Ignore the Blue line]

Comment: "We bought" then you can probably ask them for support, can't you?

Comment: Yeah, we did. No response yet.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and tried (as the documentation says) to put UFLicense.dat in the same directory of the DLLs, that is, root of where I was developing/debugging, then I put a copy of the DLL and DAT files on **C:\Windows\system32** and **C:\Windows\SysWOW64**, and it worked

**NOTE**: On System32 you should put the x64 version of the DLLs, while on SysWOW64 the 32 bit version, is a little tricky, but you can check about this on

[Why do 64-bit DLLs go to System32 and 32-bit DLLs to SysWoW64 on 64-bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949959/why-do-64-bit-dlls-go-to-system32-and-32-bit-dlls-to-syswow64-on-64-bit-windows)