# Meteor 1.1: "meteor create x" creates file in SysWOW64 on Windows 7, 64x

Tags: meteor, windows-7-x64, system32, syswow64

I'm on a 64x Windows 7 machine, and just downloaded the new Windows Meteor platform. I have no trouble creating a "Meteor" file within Windows32, but when I then use the "meteor create experiment" command to create meteor specific files within my "Meteor" file, it creates the new file on SysWOW64, instead. If I try to change directory from within the System32 file, I get a "This system cannot find the path specified" message. No problem if I cd to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Meteor\experiment".

I can't imagine meteor 1.1 is 32 bit, so how can I stop the computer from redirecting the file creation process?

As a warning, I am truly a newbie to programming. Please don't tell me to do things without also making clear what I'll need to learn to be able to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you creating projects inside the System32 directory in the first place? That's a system folder you shouldn't touch lightly. Create your projects in some other place like `C:\Projects`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. I was simply following the directions from "Your First Meteor App," which started me off by creating directories by using the "mkdir" command. That automatically created files in System32, but I couldn't then change to the meteor specific files (because, i eventually discovered, they were redirected to SysWOW64). I'll use a separate directory from now on, and hopefully that will solve the problems with accessing the created files, too.

Answer (score 0):

The default meteor installer appears to be 32 bit (You can verify this by running `meteor --arch` in the command line, which should print `os.windows.x86_32`). This is the reason why the new file is created in SysWOW64 instead.

It's also not really a good idea to create projects inside of System32 to begin with, as it is reserved for windows system files.

Comment: Also check out this question for why it is placed in SysWOW64: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949959/why-do-64-bit-dlls-go-to-system32-and-32-bit-dlls-to-syswow64-on-64-bit-windows

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense of what was happening, though I have no idea why Meteor would be 32 bit. I presume that I would be best off creating the programs in a folder outside of either System32 or SysWOW64, so that's what I'll do.