# Why can't I copy a DLL from C:\SysWOW64 from the command line?

Tags: windows, dll

> I know what I'm doing is weird, please don't worry about that. What is *happening*, however, is absolutely insane.

If I try to copy a DLL file from `C:\SysWOW32\` from the command line using `copy` on Windows 7 64-bit, I actually end up getting the file that's in `C:\System32\`. Why is this happening?

**OK - dumpbin is able to differentiate the DLL files**

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>dumpbin /headers C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll | grep machine
            8664 machine (x64)

C:\Users\user\Desktop>dumpbin /headers C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll | grep machine
             14C machine (x86)
             32 bit word machine
```

**NOT OK - Other commands, like md5sum (from [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow)) get the wrong bytes!**

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>md5sum C:\Windows\system32\opengl32.dll
\d1bbe227367ed791d5fcf08e132d2956 *C:\\Windows\\system32\\opengl32.dll

C:\Users\user\Desktop>md5sum C:\Windows\SysWow64\opengl32.dll
\d1bbe227367ed791d5fcf08e132d2956 *C:\\Windows\\SysWow64\\opengl32.dll
```

**NOT OK - Copying a 64-bit DLL using the command line**

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>copy C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll .
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\Users\user\Desktop>dir opengl32.dll
07/13/2009  06:16 PM           791,552 opengl32.dll

C:\Users\user\Desktop>md5sum opengl32.dll
d1bbe227367ed791d5fcf08e132d2956 *opengl32.dll

C:\Users\user\Desktop>dumpbin /headers opengl32.dll | grep machine
             14C machine (x86)
             32 bit word machine
```

Wrong! Why did the 32-bit DLL get copied??

**OK - Copying a 32-bit DLL using the command line**

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>copy C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll .
Overwrite .\opengl32.dll? (Yes/No/All): yes
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\Users\user\Desktop>dir opengl32.dll
07/13/2009  06:16 PM           791,552 opengl32.dll

C:\Users\user\Desktop>md5sum C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll
\d1bbe227367ed791d5fcf08e132d2956 *C:\\Windows\\System32\\opengl32.dll

C:\Users\user\Desktop>dumpbin /headers opengl32.dll | grep machine
             14C machine (x86)
             32 bit word machine
```

**OK - Copying a 64-bit DLL using Explorer**

```
<control-drag System32\opengl32.dll to desktop>

C:\Users\user\Desktop>dir opengl32.dll
07/13/2009  06:41 PM         1,039,872 opengl32.dll

C:\Users\user\Desktop>md5sum opengl32.dll
585fed4cdb8034b8b58aeb8008255817 *opengl32.dll

C:\Users\user\Desktop>dumpbin /headers opengl32.dll | grep machine
            8664 machine (x64)
```

**OK - Copying a 32-bit DLL using Explorer**

```
<control-drag SysWow64\opengl32.dll to desktop>

C:\Users\user\Desktop>dir opengl32.dll
07/13/2009  06:16 PM           791,552 opengl32.dll

C:\Users\user\Desktop>md5sum opengl32.dll
d1bbe227367ed791d5fcf08e132d2956 *opengl32.dll

C:\Users\user\Desktop>dumpbin /headers opengl32.dll | grep machine
             14C machine (x86)
             32 bit word machine
```

Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Comment: Are you doing the `copy` operation from the `Visual Studio Command Prompt`?

Comment: See answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949959/why-do-64-bit-dlls-go-to-system32-and-32-bit-dlls-to-syswow64-on-64-bit-windows (access to system32 is redirected for 32 bit programs to syswow64).

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, or I've at least sourced `vsvarsall.bat` from a regular prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you see is caused by [SysWOW64 File System Redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

`md5sum.exe` is a 32-bit binary, so when it requests `C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll`, the file system returns `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll`.

Similarly, if you launch a 32-bit prompt (`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`), perform a `copy` operation and inputs the argument `C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll`, `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll` is copied

Comment: @apaidnerd Yes, the `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` function is [pretty easy to work with as well](http://serverfault.com/questions/678529/powershell-script-not-working-when-launched-from-ssh-or-winexe-from-a-mac-or-l/678530#678530)