# Starting a vm "Windows XP Mode" programmatically through a C# program Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, virtual-machine, xp-mode

Ok, so I'm having an issue starting the the Windows XP mode VM through a c# program.  The command I'm using is `vmwindow -file "absolute path to vmcx file`" , but the problem is that the command does not work with the cmd prompt that my program kicks off.  So, it's very weird.  I can go to command prompt on my computer and run this command on my computer and it works, but if i have the same command on my c# program, the command prompt that pops up tells me the "vmwindow" is not a recognized command. I even looked at the paths of each of the command prompts and they're different, but they still both contain "C:\Windows\system32\" which is where vmwindow.exe exists.  So, I navigate on the command prompt window that my program populated and the file "vmwindow.exe" is not there, but if I open a command prompt window from my computer and navigate to that folder, it exists there.  I can't think of anything else as I already made sure they're both running in administrator mode, and also i tried starting a bat file which contained that command instead of running the command directly. Hope anyone knows anything about this.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 

        Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"<my path>";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/k vmwindow.exe -file \"<path to vcmx file>\\Windows XP Mode.vmcx\"";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
    }
```

Comment: The program (file name) should be `vmwindow.exe`, not cmd.exe. The arguments are everything after `vmwindow` in your example.

Comment: Ok, i tried this and it gave me this:            


    An unhandled exception of type     'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

    Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified.           


I feel this has to do with the command prompt window not finding vmwindow.exe when i navigate to that folder within the command prompt window that is populated by visual studio.

Comment: You need to specify the full path to `vmwindow.exe`.

Comment: same error.  I tried : 

   startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\vmwindow.exe";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's because of the bitness setting you compile your program with. ("Platform target" and "Prefer 32-bit" settings under the build tab of the project).
32 and 64 bit processes see different files under System32.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/950011

Comment: yeah, tried this and this works.  It is now starting my vm. I changed the platform target to "x64" which automatically unchekced the "Prefer 32-bit" setting, and it works now.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is using Powershell. It has a native integration for Hyper V control and is easy to [call from c#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.aspx)

You can see all HV-cmdlets [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848559%28v=wps.630%29.aspx)

a simple command to start your machine would be

```
Start-VM "Windows 8.1 Pro" -Computername HV-Host1
// etcetc
Stop-VM "Windows 8.1 Pro" -Save
```

So this should be something like this in C#

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Start-VM "Windows 8.1 Pro" -Computername HV-Host1");
}
```