# Loading Visual Basic application

Tags: vb6

I recently moved one of the old Visual basic application from one computer to another computer (windows 10). When I tried to load the application on the new computer. I get the following errors:

```
 ACTBar.ocx could not be loaded-- Continue loading projects.
```

I clicked Yes then I got another error saying:

```
Resize32.ocx could not be loaded-- Continue loading projects.
```

I said Yes again Then I got another error saying :

```
TDBG5.OCX and then Crystl32.OCX and then Comctl32.OCX could not be loaded
```

In order to start rsolving the first .OCX error, I copied this ACTBAR.OCX from my old computer and put it in  windows/system32  manually. I tried to register the .OCX regsvr32 command, but got an error saying "The module "ACTBAR.OCX" failed to load. Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems.   I tried to unregister then and got the same error. How can I overcome these .ocx issues. This application was written by another developer.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please see this link: [Why do 64-bit DLLs go to System32 and 32-bit DLLs to SysWoW64 on 64-bit Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949959/why-do-64-bit-dlls-go-to-system32-and-32-bit-dlls-to-syswow64-on-64-bit-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In windows 10, I need to put these .ocx files in c:\windows\syswow64 directory and then register them and the error will go away.