# I am trying to connect oracle 12 c db using my automation anywhere client

Tags: oracle, rpa, automationanywhere

I am trying to connect oracle 12 c db using my automation anywhere client . However i get the below error . 
Unable to initialize provider , Oracle client and networking components not found .

what is tried : 
I understand its because of missing ODAC components and i did download and install them but i am clueless what to do next as its still giving the same error . Is there some configuration required ?

At the end of ODAC installation there were instructions to run some sql files as below .

```
InstallOracleASPNETCommon.sql
InstallOracleMembership.sql
InstallOraclePersonalization.sql
InstallOracleProfile.sql
InstallOracleRoles.sql
InstallOracleSiteMap.sql
InstallOracleWebEvents.sql
InstallOracleSessionState.sql
```

I ran them all however not sure they even relate to my issue . 
I still get the error . 
My AA client and ODAC and Oracle 12c all are in 64 bit and so is my machine . 
I have verified username , password and the service name(tns) and they are good . it is the odac issue and i am unable to resolve it .

Answer (score 0):

Trust that you are well.

if i understood you question correctly , you are unable to connect AA client with Oracle 12 g, right?

1) install SQL developer or any other supporting oracle IDE tool in your machine and check if you are able to connect to database. check if correct tns is used.
if you are getting correct results in oracle tools which will confirm that your oracle is working fine in your machine( all drivers are present).

2) Create new ODBC connection in your machine. test it if connection is success or not.

Please read ODBC pre-requisited article : https://stackoverflow.com/a/950011/2966352

Once you are done with ODBC connection , try to connect to newly created ODBC via AA client and collect results.

try this and let me know if you are able to solve this.

Regards,

NoSpaceForLove