# Python: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found, Console Working, but Project Interpreter NO

Tags: python, dll, console, pycharm, importerror

I have the error "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found" when trying to import some Python Packets as Scipy and SKlearn. I have search in other post and I came up with the solution: download 2 .dll libraries_ MSVCP71.dll and msvcr71.dll and put them in C:\Windows\SysWOW64,

After that moment I can correctly Run my script in Pycharm Console, but it continues not working in Pycharm Project Interpreter. I have the same interpreter for Console and project, checked by:

```
import sys; print(sys.version)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:/Users/XX/test.py
3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Checking further I have noticed that the DLL Libraries are different in Console and in Project, do you know how can I configure same DLL paths for Project and Console?

Checked by:

```
import win32process

for process in win32process.EnumProcessModules(-1):
    name = win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(-1, process)
    # if "python27.dll" in name:
    print(name)
```

With the project interpreter I got:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python37.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\VCRUNTIME140.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHLWAPI.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPTSP.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcrypt.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python3.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_socket.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\select.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSASN1.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\libssl-1_1-x64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\libmmd.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\libifcoremd.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\imagehlp.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\mkl_rt.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\fftpack_lite.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\mtrand.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\mkl_intel_thread.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\libiomp5md.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\mkl_core.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\mkl_avx2.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\mkl_vml_avx2.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\win32process.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\pywintypes37.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Psapi.dll
```

and with console interpreter(the same interpreter) I got:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python37.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\VCRUNTIME140.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHLWAPI.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPTSP.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcrypt.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python3.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_socket.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\select.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSASN1.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\libssl-1_1-x64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\libmmd.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\libifcoremd.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\imagehlp.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\mkl_rt.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\fftpack_lite.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\mtrand.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\mkl_intel_thread.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\libiomp5md.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\mkl_core.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\mkl_avx2.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\mkl_vml_avx2.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_queue.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\win32api.pyd
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\pywintypes37.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\secur32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SSPICLI.DLL
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\_win32sysloader.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin\pythoncom37.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
c:\Program Files\HP\HP ProtectTools Security Manager\Bin\DpoFeedb.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\urlmon.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\iertutil.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_contextvars.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_asyncio.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_overlapped.pyd
C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_sqlite3.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin\sqlite3.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyodbc.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ODBC32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DPAPI.DLL
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslib.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\np_datetime.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\nattype.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\timedeltas.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\timezones.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\parsing.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\ccalendar.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\fields.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\hashtable.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\missing.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\algos.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\properties.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\hashing.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bottleneck\reduce.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bottleneck\nonreduce.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bottleneck\nonreduce_axis.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bottleneck\move.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\period.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\frequencies.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\resolution.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\offsets.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\join.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\ops.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\interval.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\indexing.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\internals.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\sparse.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_path.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\window.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\skiplist.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\reduction.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\groupby.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\reshape.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\json.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\writers.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\msgpack\_packer.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\msgpack\_unpacker.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_move.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\testing.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\_constant_time.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_cffi_backend.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\_openssl.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_ccallback_c.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\_ufuncs.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libopenblas.IPBC74C7KURV7CB2PKT5Z5FNR3SIBV4J.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libdgamln.L2MD744DJHVE3HDIDGQFBRBYHR75FSAI.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\_ufuncs_cxx.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\specfun.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libspecfun.BHLTWMBI4EYWDACZN4DQUESSDJRJNGEL.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_fblas.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libwrap_dum.Y5YNB62CEIOAELCP2WZDLJGRR3KZYA7H.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_flapack.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libwrap_dum.MRQ7UAVPNY36S6LDFETEBLDUEUIEUBHR.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_flinalg.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libdet.MC6JBNE6VNYD6FNPXJKRRGWJPYV2NN2N.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_solve_toeplitz.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_decomp_update.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\cython_blas.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\lib_blas_su.NB4WQJWKUFT4P25L5KENNGUG4L73EMTU.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\cython_lapack.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\_comb.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\_ellip_harm_2.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_fitpack.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libbispeu.5N2XSD7URZS4WTOSLTOG4DDMA4HGB46U.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\dfitpack.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libdfitpack.PJU6IBGOYZCWITNVROHYOQAYNGAXO3HT.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_bspl.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_ppoly.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpnd.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_sparsetools.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_csparsetools.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_shortest_path.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_tools.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_traversal.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_min_spanning_tree.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_reordering.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\ckdtree.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\qhull.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\messagestream.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\_voronoi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\_distance_wrap.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\_hausdorff.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin\zlib.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin\tiff.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack2.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libdcsrch.I2AOPDCXAPDRFNPWY55H5UE7XZSU5CVN.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trlib\_trlib.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\_iterative.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libgetbreak.3JNHTDZYEWBO45P4ZRQMAM3G2F777JB5.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\dsolve\_superlu.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\_arpack.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\lib_arpack-.XS6PLV3734SEBIN3L7VHQL4V6AFVR3MS.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_group_columns.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_lbfgsb.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\liblbfgsb.UBS3OB2ZGZATGJADSNFQXG6JBUJXYZFS.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\moduleTNC.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_cobyla.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libcobyla2.JEGTSUUFJ7DFXWZN5PAYZTTLBDATC4WD.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_slsqp.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libslsqp_op.LIFGE6AEK5GZMIV4YAH6Q4UEDG4INU5S.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libchkder.G7WSOGIYYQO3UWFVEZ3PPXCXR53ADVPA.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_lsq\givens_elimination.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_zeros.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_nnls.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libnnls.IXEEHJUCGHJL42YZEM6UIEMROJWXHMLJ.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_odepack.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libblkdta00.ZGG7V3JKZ4GEJEF2MTA5BHMT7BJIUCKN.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_quadpack.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libdqag.NBT4GJCYXTJZ6FKYPTMU262SBAG2QI76.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\vode.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libvode.UPE44X4HLFF56JWPT3ESOS5IVN5QQ5A4.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_dop.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libdop853.6TJTQZW3I3Q3QIDQHEOBEZKJ3NYRXI4B.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\lsoda.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_stats.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\statlib.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libansari.R6EA3HQP5KZ6TAXU4Y4ZVTRPT7UVA53Z.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\mvn.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll\libmvndst.5VXNIPAPINAF5NIHXAFNA4OTHOPNDEWG.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_multiprocessing.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build\_check_build.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\murmurhash.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\_psutil_windows.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio_utils.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio5_utils.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\streams.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_logistic_sigmoid.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\sparsefuncs_fast.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_elementtree.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\tk86t.dll
C:\WINDOWS\System32\COMDLG32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NETAPI32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.17763.379_none_05b83be8071c94a1\COMCTL32.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LOGONCLI.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SAMCLI.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NETUTILS.DLL
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\_hashing.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_random.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\_svmlight_format.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\libsvm.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\liblinear.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\libsvm_sparse.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\seq_dataset.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\arrayfuncs.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\cluster\expected_mutual_info_fast.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\lgamma.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise_fast.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\cd_fast.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\sgd_fast.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\weight_vector.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\sag_fast.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\ball_tree.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\dist_metrics.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\typedefs.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\kd_tree.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
C:\windows\system32\msodbcsql17.dll
C:\windows\system32\WININET.dll
C:\windows\system32\MSVCR120.dll
C:\windows\system32\MSVCP120.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MTXDM.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll
C:\Windows\System32\comsvcs.dll
C:\windows\system32\1033\msodbcsqlr17.rll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\netbios.dll
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CLUSAPI.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\RESUTILS.DLL
C:\WINDOWS\system32\schannel.DLL
```

Where you can see in the Console interpreter I have the line:

```
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140.dll
```

Which I think is the one that make it works,

How can I add this dll path to the project interpreter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't the problem that you try to run packages made for Windows64 on a Windows32 system? Maybe you do not have the proper Anaconda distribution: Check https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/hashes/win-3-32/ versus https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/hashes/win-3-64/

Comment: No, I have already checked and they are both in 64bits system

Comment: This could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949959/why-do-64-bit-dlls-go-to-system32-and-32-bit-dlls-to-syswow64-on-64-bit-windows

Comment: I cannot solve the issue, the point is that in Run Command I got error:

from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida.

But on Console I don't get error and works, how can I troubleshoot it in order to see the problem? Both sys.executables are the same, Anaconda 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]

Answer (score -1):

Try [2019.1.3 RC build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=23004355). I believe you are facing a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35141) and it was fixed there.